# Solr Spark indexing failure due to an error accessing the collection

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04, solr, apache-spark

I am using Solr with Spark in Java to index documents.  (Ubuntu 16.0.4)
I have set Zookeeper running on port 2181 and my collection test has two shards

When I launch my code I have a java.lang.NullPointerException.

Here is my code (the class for indexing only):

```js
public class SparkRead implements Serializable  {

    private Integer nbLinesToSkip;
    private Integer lineNumber = 0;
    private String fileName;
    private Integer sizeToRead;
    private Integer increment = 0;


    public SparkRead(Integer nbLinesToSkip) {
        this.nbLinesToSkip = nbLinesToSkip;
    }

    public void loadDocuments(String pathToFile) {


        ArrayList<document> Documents = new ArrayList<>();



        // configure spark
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Read Text to RDD")
                .setMaster("local[2]").set("spark.executor.memory","2g");
        // start a spark context
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

        // provide path to input text file
        String path = pathToFile;

        // read text file to RDD
        JavaRDD<String> documents = sc.textFile(path, 1000);

        JavaRDD<String[]> lines = documents.map(document -> {
            return document.split("\\r?\\n");
        });



        JavaRDD<String[]> header = sc.parallelize(lines.take(1));

        lines = lines.subtract(header);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lines.take(1).get(0)));

        JavaRDD<document> sDocs = lines.map(x ->  getDocumentFromLine(Arrays.toString(x), lineNumber));






        JavaRDD<SolrInputDocument> solrInputDocuments = sDocs.map(x -> getSolrInputDocument(x));




        String zkHost = "127.0.0.1:2181" ;

        SolrSupport.indexDocs(zkHost,"test", 1, solrInputDocuments.rdd());   


}
```

Here is the error:

```js
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: Error from server at http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/test_shard1_replica_n1: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.mapValueClassesToFieldType(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:509)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory$AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory.java:396)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory$1.processAdd(FieldNameMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.java:75)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.processAdd(FieldMutatingUpdateProcessor.java:118)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.update.processor.AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory$DefaultValueUpdateProcessor.processAdd(AbstractDefaultValueUpdateProcessorFactory.java:92)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader$1.update(JavabinLoader.java:98)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readOuterMostDocIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:188)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readIterator(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:144)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:311)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec$1.readNamedList(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:130)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readObject(JavaBinCodec.java:276)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.readVal(JavaBinCodec.java:256)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.JavaBinCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinCodec.java:178)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.unmarshal(JavaBinUpdateRequestCodec.java:195)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.parseAndLoadDocs(JavabinLoader.java:108)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.loader.JavabinLoader.load(JavabinLoader.java:55)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.UpdateRequestHandler$1.load(UpdateRequestHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:68)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:177)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2503)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:710)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:516)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:382)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at
```

.
.
.

The shard actually exists and so does the shar1 replica and the url
127.0.0.1:8983/solr/#/test_shard1_replica_n1  actually works too.

I really don't know what is the problem and I have been looking for a solution for a while.

Thank you!